# custom field background image

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have looked high and low for this, but can't seem to find an answer... I have a wordpress site that used custom fields and can upload images to it and basic copy in a tinyMCE, but I was wondering if there's a way to have it so that a user could upload a background image to wordpress, and then have it appear on the site in the area that's designated?

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to upload / edit fields.

One idea I have, is to have it so that a  calls an absolute url that a user uploads stuff to... but the problem is that if a user uploads down the line, wordpress would change the url of where things are uploaded.  For example, img src="october2013/backgroundimage", 2 months down the line it would be img src="december2013/backgroundimage".

Is there a way I can designate the url an image is uploaded to in wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this!  Just put it as a background image to the url.... like this:

```
 <div style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('headerimagegraphic');?>); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```